# Problem SAX parsing data that contains international characters

Tags: android, parsing, sax

I am using SAX parser in an Android project to parse the google weather xml in the french language and I get the error,

org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 502: not well-formed (invalid token)

When I get the xml in the default (English) language the parsing works fine. I assume that the error has to do with the international characters in the xml, but how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell your parser that your xml stream is UTF-8 encoded.

[Read this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) for details.